# File - undefined due to data-ng-if while uploading file in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, file, upload, undefined

I am working with file upload using the angularJs 1.3
I have a situation where the controller can access the file without the data-ng-if in the  tag, but if I include the data-ng-if the file in the controller is undefined can anyone help me understand more about the issue, and a solution that I can use data-ng-if while uploading the file

```
<div ng-controller = "QuestionsListController">
    <form id="questionForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" data-ng-submit="uploadForm()">
        <p>
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-if="isTestQuestion">
                <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
            </div>
        </p>        
        <button type="submit">upload me</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

the script that contains controller and service and directive

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileAndFieldsToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(data){
            console.log("success : ",data);
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("fail");
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadForm = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
        var uploadUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/ajax/recruiter/codingQuestion';
        fileUpload.uploadFileAndFieldsToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

I can see the file in the directive using the console.log()
thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What is `isTestQuestion`? It's not in the code you provided and therefor may be `undefined`, so the `ngIf` resolves to `false`. On the other hand, you provide code for a controller named `myCtrl`, but in the template you use `QuestionsListController`.

Comment: isTestQuestion is a boolean variable, it is defined as true.. and the controller , my mistake, but I use the myCtrl in the ng-controller .and find the  same status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-if creates a new scope for the dom elements within the 'form-group' div.
Use ng-show instead